# Select All in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, select

How can I select all values in my table.

So I have table CustomerTables with this atributes:

IdCust; (int - PK)
UserId; (int - FK)
Customer; (string)

I start with this code:

```
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
  using (var dbContext = new userDbEntities())
  {
  var deleteCust = dbContext.CustomerTables.Where(m => m.UserId == id).Select(m => m.???); 
  }
}
```

So how to in **.Select(m => m.???)** select all values in Table CustomerTable?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can omit the `Select()` and you'll get a collection of `CustomerTable` objects. Assuming your `CustomerTable` model contains all values from the table and they are properly mapped, you should have access to all values...

```
var deleteCust = dbContext.CustomerTables.Where(m => m.UserId == id);
```